# .htaccess Prevent from running in parallel across multiple domains

Tags: .htaccess

I have two domains:

www.mywebsite.com
www.my-website.com

I want all traffic going to my-website.com (no www.)

In the .htaccess for www.mywebsite.com I currently have the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.my\-website\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

In the .htaccess for www.my-website.com I currently have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.111\.111\.111
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.my-website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am looking for the correct way to write both .htaccess files so everything goes to my-website.com and prevent from running in parallel.

Comment: Only the pattern is a regular expression, escaping in the replacement part of a RewriteRule is wrong. And why are you trying to redirect to the www-version if your are saying you only want to use the non-www one? And why do you expect your site to be requested via an IP address (which is _not_ a host name)?

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: What I have "currently" is not what I want going forward, hence the reason I am looking for suggestions to make it the way I want it going forward.

Comment: To answer "And why do you expect your site to be requested via an IP address (which is not a host name)?" Based on a suggestion of IP Canonicalization

Comment: But I am not sure what you mean by `prevent from running in parallel` here.

Comment: where the www and non www version are viewed as two different sites. I have answered my own question after trial and error...which I will post.

Answer (score 0):

in www.mywebsite.com .htaccess I entered the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite.com$
 RewriteRule (.*)$ http://my-website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

in www.my-website.com I entered the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my-website\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://my-website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @anubhava - actually I didn't.  I had no code in the my-website.com .htaccess to rewrite from www. to non at all and I had to change the mywebsite.com .htaccess to the non www url.  I however appreciate your time.

Comment: In your question you have posted `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.111\.111\.111` for `my-website.com .htaccess` as well. You just changed condition to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my-website\.com`